# Equivalent to style.css on ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I want to customize ionic 2 theme, and I'm new to inoic. Usually when creating a template we create style.css file that's used for most of the pages, and I need to customize ionic main theme (like adding border to navbar, changing colors, etc.)

Comment: See [Overriding Ionic Sass Variables](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)

Comment: I did before, doesnt contain everything... and where should use those variables in which file that could be similar to style.css

Comment: Then add custom css in **src/app/app.scss**

Comment: exactly thanks.. write it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add custom css in **src/app/app.scss**